# How to call StartDragAsync from CoreIndependentInputSource Pointer event UWP

Tags: uwp, drag-and-drop, c++-cx

I have a UWP Application where CoreIndependentInputSource is used to get pointer events

As its runs on Separate Thread and so PointerPressed/Moved/Relased also triggered on separate thread

```
    coreInput = swapChainPanel->CreateCoreIndependentInputSource(
            CoreInputDeviceTypes::Mouse |
            CoreInputDeviceTypes::Touch |
            CoreInputDeviceTypes::Pen
            );

        // Register for pointer events, which will be raised on the dedicated input thread.
        coreInput->PointerPressed += ref new TypedEventHandler<Object^, PointerEventArgs^>(this, &Scenario1_LowLatencyInput::OnPointerPressed);
        .
        .
        coreInput->Dispatcher->ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption::ProcessUntilQuit);
    }); 
inputLoopWorker = ThreadPool::RunAsync(inputWorkItemHandler, WorkItemPriority::High, WorkItemOptions::TimeSliced);
```

UWP StartDragAsync function needs PointerPoint as parameter
But this function need to be called from UI thread.

Unfortunately PointerPoint Object has thread affinity. So as its created in Input Dispatcher Thread it can not be passed to UI thread

```
void Scenario1_LowLatencyInput::OnPointerPressed(Object^ sender, PointerEventArgs^ args)
{
    // Event Received in Input Dispatcher Thread 
    PointerPoint^ currentPoint = args->CurrentPoint;

    this->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal,
              ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this, currentPoint]()
    {
        // Have to run on UI thread for StartDragAsync
        DragUIItem->StartDragAsync(currentPoint); //!!!! Exception will occur here because currentPoint is not created in UI thread

    }));
```

- If I call DragUIItem->StartDragAsync in InputDispatcher Thread then Exception occurs because  StartDragAsync need to be called from UI thread.
- If I pass this point to DragUIItem->StartDragAsync in UI thread then Exception occurs because currentPoint created in InputDispatcher thread so StartDragAsync Function (which is now executing in UI thread) can not use it

Does any knows how to overcome this problem.

Comment: *"Does any knows how to overcome this problem."* - By following the basic ground rule of UI programming: Handle *all* input on the UI thread.

Comment: Not an option,
for my task purpose, I must use CreateCoreIndependentInputSource for input taking mechanism

Comment: It's impossible to use the `point` from another thread to call the `StartDragAsync` method.    It only receives the `point` from the UI thread. So you have to handle the in put in the UI thread.

Comment: this application uses DirectX based rendering so input need to be taken in LowLatency Thread. So what can be other alternative way to start drag operation ?

Comment: A possible workaround is that you might need to handle the pressed event and pointer move on your own. When both of the events happen, move the item to the positon of the pointer.

Comment: tried similar concept but when events received on swapChainPanel->CreateCoreIndependentInputSource,    then no input event triggered from other pointer input event handlers (i.e.  Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow PointerPressed/Moved etc or swapChainPanel->PointerPressed/PointerMoved etc)